# C# EMIT IL for multi-value generic classes?

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-construction

I am doing a runtime / reflection / emit type process. I've got it working, so I understand the basics. I need to expand it to support Dictionaries, but would like to make it generic enough to expand to other multi-value generic classes. The idea is to copy one dictionary to another, but I need to foreach get / insert the items as they may need to be manipulated along the way...

`Dictionary<int, string>` is an ICollection of `KeyValuePair<int, string>`.

So, if I do GetGenericArguments on the dictionary, I get:

```
int
string
```

Awesome. So, how do I know that the int property ties to Key and string ties to Value?

Lets say it was a `Tuple<T1, T2, T3>`, I'd have the same issue of having to know T1 is Item1, T2 is Item3, etc.

I thought about reflecting on `KeyValuePair<int, string>` GetProperties() and then I'd get int Key, string Value, but then I'd have to guarantee that Key is the first param and Value is the 2nd... .NET works in this regard because classes like KeyValuePair / Tuple keep the properties in the same order.

.Net also keeps the params in order... in a tuple for example, T1, T2, T3, the params for the constructor are item1, item2, item3 and the property names are Item1, Item2, Item3, so you can tie everything together... but that can't really be guaranteed.

Theoretically, a source / destination has to be the same internal type, i.e. KeyValuePair'2 to KeyValuePair'2, but it can also theoretically be int, int and int, string since a int is "castable" to a string.

You guys get what I mean? Any ideas?

EDIT:

The dynamically generated Emit code needs to basically do:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<int, int> kvp in sourceDict)
{
   destDict.Add(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
}
```

I was trying to avoid "knowing about dictionaries", but based on your responses, that seems unavoidable?

Lets say Bob invents a new Dictionary that is O(0.000000001) LOL for example for all operations, so everybody switches to that implementation and now the C# code to copy the dictionary would be:

```
foreach (BobKeyValuePair<int, int> kvp in sourceDict)
{
   destDict.Add(kvp.bKey, kvp.aValue);
}
```

Or whatever, because Bob is only good at optimization, but not at naming stuff correctly. So now I'd have to know about both Key/Value and bKey/aValue which is what I'm trying to avoid.

Theoretically a `Dictionary<int, int>` is "castable" to a `List<Tuple<int, int>>` in my app... I guess that's not really going to be possible in a generic manner.

Comment: `GetGenericArguments` is guaranteed to give you the arguments in order, because the order of generic arguments *matter*. You can't *generally* know that the first item is key, and the second item is value, because that's specific to dictionaries. If it's truly generic, you *wouldn't* care. Since you are explicitly copying dictionaries, you can hard-code the rule that the order of generic arguments are correct.

Comment: You cannot reasonably make it more generic, you have to know about what you are going to do - **somewhere**, there needs to be a specification saying that dictionaries have keys, values, how they work and what they can do. Why not make your component know about dictionaries and make them a first class type?

Comment: As @Rob implies, you're totally overthinking this.  I know it can *seem* distasteful to rely on order when that order can be unpredictable -- that is often the case.  But in this scenario it is literally impossible for that to be the case.  The order is guaranteed by spec.  So you are free to rely on it.

Comment: Similarly, it is completely safe to rely on parameter order for arguments passed into a function for a given overload (ignoring named arguments, for which the rule is true but the explanation more subtle).

Comment: @Rob, updated original post in response

Comment: @KirkWoll, updated original post is response. Might be over thinking it LOL, not sure yet...

Comment: @SledgeHammer In your example yes, you *must* know about how a dictionary works to provide the translation. There isn't really any other way to go about it. In your `int`/`int` example, it's possible that Bob made a mistake and reversed the key and value properties. There's no real hard and fast rule other than `bKey` is *probably* `Key` because it has a similar name. But that might not be the case, so there's no way to write a generic rule. You need to hard code it.